# How to maintain control in center with anchor(left,right)/dock(fill) and maximum width

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-designer

Let's say we have form with docked GroupBox. GroupBox have docked TableLayoutPanel with 2 rows (50% height each). Each row have Button. I want this buttons to be centered in TableLayoutPanel cells, expanding with form but also have a maximum width.

Example form:

[image: ex_form_img]

If I use anchor(left,right) or dock(fill) and then set maximum width for buttons, they stay on left side of cells. Is there a way to do what I want (have button in center when reached max width) using only designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- turn OFF all anchors for each button to keep it in the center of the parent container without changing their size

  OR
- center each button and then turn ON all its anchors to keep it in the center expanding with the parent container

But you cannot achieve limiting the button size together with centering. You can do it only dynamically, through code.

Comment: First of all you can't change location of control manually in tableLayout cell. Second, with turned OFF anchors is weird thing happening. In designer, button is increasing/decreasing width nicely, but when you start application button is expanding only to the size it had when compiled, not to the maximum size property.

Comment: "But you cannot achieve limiting the button size together with centering. You can do it only dynamically, through code." That's what I was asking for, I know I can do it through code, but I prefer do as most as I can in designer.

Comment: @rastaqki – yes I understand you prefer it by smart design. I also think the same way whenever possible. So basically here I tested the behavior and confirmed this is not possible in this case. And my apologies for inaccuracy – I tested the button only in context of form, I did not realize that in TableLayoutCell it can behave somewhat differently. But yeah, we tried all possible designer ways so now we know they lead nowhere.